# Windows Antimalware Scan Interface thread safety

Tags: windows, winapi, virus-scanning

The Windows Antimalware scan Interface (AMSI) contains abstractions which can be used to call the currently active virus scanner in Windows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/amsi/antimalware-scan-interface-functions

There are 2 methods related to initialization:

- AmsiInitialize
- AmsiUninitialize

AmsiInitialize returns "*A handle of type HAMSICONTEXT that must be passed to all subsequent calls to the AMSI API.*".

After initialization is complete, I can use AmsiScanBuffer to scan a buffer for malware.

My question:

Can I use the same context concurrently from many threads in my application, or do I need to create one per thread from which I'm going to call the methods?

Reading the documentation,  for AsmiUnitialize, it tells me that *When the app is finished with the AMSI API it must call AmsiUninitialize.*. This tells me that the context can be used for many calls, but it doesn't tell me anything about thread safety or concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, API calls that are not specifically marked as thread-safe are not (this is usually true for any library). The easiest solution is to open an AMSI handle per thread.

(P.S. This only works with Windows Defender so far as I 've tested).

Comment: Yeah Microsoft's documentation really ain't what it used to be. I agree with this, though if you open a new AMSI context for each thread you might want to provide it a new `appName` to be safe too. Maybe a random Guid. That said, I think it's *likely* that sharing the context between threads is fine (I definitely wouldn't share the session), but there's no way to know without testing.